# ResourceMock.js not resolving correct URL

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am using ResourceMock.js to fake the data and return some custome product data.
Thing's work fine when I try to get the product list and hit url /products

but then for specific product I want to pass the product id and the URL will be like /product/edit?productId.

I am trying to get the functionality using some regex stuff but its not working as expected.

The error logged in console is  Unexpected request: GET /api/products?productId=4

```
//working fine for getting list of all products. :)
 var producturl = "/api/products";
        $httpBackend.whenGET(producturl).respond(products);

//when try to get specific item things goes wrong. :(
        var editRegex = new RegExp(producturl + "/[A-Za-z0-9]", '');
        alert(editRegex);
        $httpBackend.whenGET(editRegex).respond(function(method, url, data) {
//do some stuff and return
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=[A-Za-z0-9]
```

You are not matching the `=`.Include it in prodcuturl or regex match.